# Did I just brick a non-rooted device?

Tags: unbricking

I have a non-rooted Onyx Boox C67ML Carta running stock Android 4.2.2.

I just installed [Orientation Locker.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.rotationlocker&hl=en) I transferred it from my phone using [Shareit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.anyshare.gps&hl=en), but on my phone it had come from the Play Store.

Once installed, when I tried to run it, the whole device totally froze. See below for a picture of what it looks like.

When this device had frozen on me before, I had always been able to force a reboot by holding down the power button. That does not work in the current situation.

I carefully used a knife to take off the back cover to try and find the battery. The battery does not seem to be removable without physically breaking the device.

I suppose I could wait for the battery to run out. It was quite low when the incident occurred. It may actually be out already, and the device off, since e-ink screens may continue to display the last picture they showed when something goes wrong, even without power.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Shall we assume that USB debugging is not enabled in your device? For how long did you long-press the power button?

Comment: USB debugging was not enabled. The problem is solved too. I'm glad the battery was very low when it happened, otherwise I might have had to wait for quite a long time.

Comment: Oh and I didn't see the second question on your first comment: I pressed the power button for at least 30 seconds, far longer than what is usually required to force a reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device was not bricked. After a few hours I held down the power button again, and the frozen screen was replaced by the "no battery" screen. After charging, the device is back to normal. I caution users of this *particular device* **not** to use apps that try to force the systemwide screen orientation.

It was lucky that the battery was nearly empty when this happened. I suspect that if the battery had been more charged, the wait could have been significantly longer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that happened because you took the app from someone else from Shareit. You have to install any app from **Play Store** (Highly recommended).

Because when you take and install the app from someone else, **if the DPI does not match**, surely your **device will stuck** as soon as you open the app.

Ex. I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2, and I am taking an app from the Samsung Galaxy S2, and installing it on my device will get the device stuck. Not for every app, some will work perfectly.